Trying to read Split Zip File throws ZipException in zip4j
I am having a split zip file test_10G.zip.001 and test_10G.zip.002. I am trying to use isSplitArchive() Function from zip4j. But I am getting an exception saying Zip headers not found. Probably not a zip file .
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SplitZipMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (ZipFile splitZip1 = new ZipFile(new File("./test_10G.zip.001"))) {
            System.out.println(splitZip1.isSplitArchive());
        }
    }
}

Does zip4j support split zip files? I am using zip4j 2.11.5. The zip file is created using 7zip with volumes split as 10 mb.

I guess you need to check last file. It checks for central directory, which is located at the end. Or you need concat those files before checking.

Split archive have extensions z01, z02... zip.
Last one contains all metainfo. You need to check it.
Here is example from documentation.

I have used 7 zip for creating this split zip file. All I get are files with extensions .zip.001, .zip.002 ... etc. I don't get a main zip file
